# GZIP Compression on Sitecore

Tags: sitecore-client

On IIS both enable dynamic content compression and enable static content compression are checked but Js and Css have content-encoding:gzip in response header while in the pages it doesn't have content-encoding in the response header.

Any advise?

Comment: What have you tried so far to get it to work? Did you look here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17654301/sitecore-mvc-gzip-compression-error